# How to update state inside a hook and read it from another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this react stateless component, the first useEffect should run after the component loads, the second one when I scroll the page, to implement infinite scroll.

What I am trying to do is to update the state inside useEffect, and then use the updated value inside the second one:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    page: 1
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({
        ...state,
        page: state.page + 1
    });
   }, []);

  useEffect(() => {

    if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
            return;
        }
    console.log(state.page);

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

}
```

unfortunately the console.log shows the page is still one, even if using the react console in chrome I can see the value has changed.

I know that useEffect is stateless so the console.log is reading the value prior to be updated, anyway how can I fix it to read the updated value?

Comment: In the second one use: `useEffect(()=>{...},[state]);

Comment: Also, you can update the question that your problem is resolved so that others not try to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second one use: `useEffect(()=>{...},[state]);`